# JPA: Eclipselink not respecting em.remove()

Tags: jpa, glassfish, ejb, eclipselink

I need to delete one entity and create another:

```
@Stateless
public class StatelessBean {
  @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "Unit001")
  EntityManagerFactory emf;

  protected void test() {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    MyObj obj1 = em.find(MyObj.class, 100);
    MyObj obj2 = new MyObj();
    obj2.setKey("the same unique key as in obj1");
    em.remove(obj1);
    // em.flush(); 
    em.persist(obj2); // works fine when flush() is uncommented
    em.close();
  }
}
```

If I leave `em.flush()` commented, then I get `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` (new and old objects have equal key value)

What could be the reason for such an abnormal behavior?

Server: Glassfish 3.1.2

Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="Unit001">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/Unit001DS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Connection pool:

```
${ASADMIN} --port ${DOMAIN_ADMIN_PORT}  create-jdbc-connection-pool --datasourceclassname com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource --restype javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource --property "User=user:Password=pass:URL=jdbc\:mysql\://${DB_ADDRESS}/db" Unit001DS
${ASADMIN} --port ${DOMAIN_ADMIN_PORT}  create-jdbc-resource --connectionpoolid Unit001DS jdbc/Unit001DS
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason could be that Eclipselink changes the order of operations during commit as stated in the [Eclipselink documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Advanced_Unit_of_Work_API_%28ELUG%29#Controlling_the_Order_of_Delete_Operations):

> By default, EclipseLink does insert and update operations first, before delete operations, to ensure that referential integrity is maintained. This is the preferred approach.

You can change this behavior either by flushing (as you already found out) or by setting a special parameter for Eclipselink:

> If you are forced to replace an object with unique constraints by
>   deleting it and inserting a replacement, you may cause a constraint
>   violation if the insert operation occurs before the delete operation.
>   In this case, call `setShouldPerformDeletesFirst` to perform the delete
>   operation before the insert operation.

Comment: Thanks, but `Other JPA implementations do it the same way` is a bit questionable to me - the very same project was absolutely fine running `Hibernate` as JPA provider.

Comment: You may be right, I am not sure about it, just read it in a different post. Will edit my answer.

Comment: are there any config options to force eclipselink generating sql as java code flows? I'm prettty low on time and would like to have hibernate-compatible solution without tweaking sql-deletes only.

Comment: I don't know any (besides `flush`).

Comment: Thanks, accepting as the question is actually answered, all other question are different story.

Answer (score 1):

EclipseLink maintains and optimizes the commit order to:

1 - maintain referential integrity constraints: if you insert two related objects (or one big interconnect graph of many objects), they must be inserted/updated/deleted in a very specific and non-obvious order to maintain referential integrity constraints.  In some cases it may even be required to insert a shell object and update its foreign keys after to resolve cyclic dependencies.  Deletes must occur last, as the objects that used to reference the deleted object must have the relationships updated first.

2 - group operations and table access: this avoids database deadlocks, and allows optimal usage of batch writing.

3 - consistently order updates/deletes by id: this is configurable, and avoids potential database deadlocks.

If EclipseLink just blindly wrote things in the order the application did things, you would have to manage all of this yourself.  I really doubt you would really want to do this.  For the cases that you really need to, you can use flush().

Comment: Sorry, I just don't believe it. We're talking of JPA implementation, not AI, aren't we? The flow of `EntityManager` calls must be respected somehow, otherwise all of my transactions would be able to end up with two unordered collections - `toPersist` and `toDelete`. And if I say `remove` in this particulat line of code, that is supposed to mean something to JPA provider. Am I right?